# libcurl curl_multi CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS memory management

Tags: c, libcurl

When is it safe to re-use the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` buffer?
I have the following code:

```
void handle_data(uint8_t *data, size_t dataLen)
{
    static uint8_t s_buffer[500];
    static size_t s_bufferIdx;

    if (s_buffer + dataLen > sizeof(s_buffer))
    {
        CURL *handle = curl_easy_init();
        curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, s_buffer);
        curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, s_bufferIdx);

        curl_multi_add_handle(s_curlM, handle);
        curl_multi_perform(s_curlMultiHandle, NULL);
        s_bufferIdx = 0;  // "Re-use" the buffer
    }

    memcpy(&s_buffer[s_bufferIdx], data, dataLen);
    s_bufferIdx += dataLen;

    // Check completed transfers and cleanup handles with `curl_multi_info_read` here
}
```

I'm guessing it's not safe so I would need to malloc a buffer for each handle, but I don't see a way to attach a `context pointer` to a CURL handle so would I need to maintain a map of handle + buffers to cleanup when I get `CURLMSG_DONE` from `curl_multi_info_read`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like if I use `CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS` instead of `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` then my above code will work.

The documentation also says that `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE` should be set before `CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS`